# Scala: how to assign an List of arrays/Lists to two variables?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have the following array of string:

```
val lines: List[String] = List("GOOL,1182", "AMZN,1920", "MSFT,124", "APPL,192.2")
```

In practice this type of array is typically obtained by reading a csv file.

Conceptually, I would like to

1. For each line, split it by ","
2. After splitting all the lines, assign the first column to a List, and the second column to another List.

The approach I came up with is the following:

```
var col1List = List[String]()
var col2List = List[String]()
lines.foreach{ x => 
  val cols = x split ","
  col1List = col1List ::: List(cols(0))
  col2List = col2List ::: List(cols(1))
}
```

Afterward, I got the following Lists:

```
List[String] = List(GOOL, AMZN, MSFT, APPL)
List[String] = List(1182, 1920, 124, 192.2)
```

Is there a better way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is `.unzip` method.

Here's an example:

```
val lines: List[String] = List("GOOL,1182", "AMZN,1920", "MSFT,124", "APPL,192.2")
val (l1, l2) = lines.map(_.split(",")).map(arr => (arr.head, arr.last)).unzip
println(l1, l2)
```

Result:

```
(List(GOOL, AMZN, MSFT, APPL),List(1182, 1920, 124, 192.2))
```

Answer (score 4):

bottaio is kind-of right, you need `unzip`. You need **NOTHING BUT `unzip`**:

```
val lines: List[String] = List("GOOL,1182", "AMZN,1920", "MSFT,124", "APPL,192.2")
val (xs, ys) = lines.unzip{ str => val a = str.split(","); (a(0), a(1)) }
println(xs)
println(ys)

// Output:
// List(GOOL, AMZN, MSFT, APPL)
// List(1182, 1920, 124, 192.2)
```

Notice that `unzip` itself accepts a function that transforms entries of the list into pairs.

Answer (score 3):

This in general, works for all sizes of lines read from `.csv` file into the `lines`
 `List`:

```
lines.map(_.split(",")).transpose
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
    scala> val lines: List[String] = List("GOOL,1182", "AMZN,1920", "MSFT,124", "APPL,192.2")
    lines: List[String] = List(GOOL,1182, AMZN,1920, MSFT,124, APPL,192.2)

    scala> lines.map(_.split(",")).transpose
    res30: List[List[String]] = List(List(GOOL, AMZN, MSFT, APPL), List(1182, 1920, 124, 192.2))

    scala> val lines: List[String] = List("GOOL,1182,23,56", "AMZN,1920,57,21", "MSFT,124,345,987", "APPL,192.2,765,908")
    lines: List[String] = List(GOOL,1182,23,56, AMZN,1920,57,21, MSFT,124,345,987, APPL,192.2,765,908)

    scala> lines.map(_.split(",")).transpose
    res29: List[List[String]] = List(List(GOOL, AMZN, MSFT, APPL), List(1182, 1920, 124, 192.2), List(23, 57, 345, 765), List(56
    , 21, 987, 908))
```